# Extract Key Value pairs which matches the regex in YAML using yq/sed/grep

Tags: regex, shell, sed, grep, yaml

I have this below YAML input and I am trying to extract shown output using `yq`

**Input:**

```
VAR-A: '{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-B: '{{a.b.VAR-B}}'
VAR-C: v0.0
VAR-D: '{{a.b.VAR-D}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-E: '{{a.b.VAR-C}}-{{a.b.VAR-B}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-F: '{{a.b.VAR-F}}'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
VAR-C: v0.0
VAR-D: '{{a.b.VAR-D}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-E: '{{a.b.VAR-C}}-{{a.b.VAR-B}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
```

**My Attempt:**

```
yq eval 'del( .[] | select (. == "{{a.b.*" ) )' abc.yaml
```

I am new to `yq` and any help will be much appreciated.

**Based on @Inian's comment**

**Note: I want to remove pairs where key name (VAR-A) in value {{a.b.VAR-A}} (after a.b.) matches and If I have more than {{a.b.VAR-A}} in values separated by - , I want to keep them

Comment: The logic doesn't make sense why should VAR-A, VAR-B, VAR-F be excluded/

Comment: @Inian I want to remove pairs where key name (`VAR-A`) in value `{{a.b.VAR-A}}`  (after `a.b.`) matches and If I have more than `{{a.b.VAR-A}}` in values separated by `-` , I want to keep them.

Comment: I don't think this is straightforward with yq

Comment: @Inian Is there any other alternatives we can approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you expected ?

```
yq eval 'del(.[] | select(sub("^{{a\.b\.[^}]+}}$","")=="" ))' abc.yaml
```

The regex `^{{a\.b\.[^}]+}}$` matches a single {{...}} structure, because of `^` and `$` at the beginning and end. `[^}]` means any character which is not `}`.

Then it substitute with empty string, if the result is again an empty string, it's selected for deletion.

If you just want to match `{{a.b.VAR-A}}`:

```
yq eval 'del(.[] | select(sub("^{{a\.b\.VAR-A}}$","")=="" ))' abc.yaml
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am expecting. But, is it possible for you to explain what you are doing with regex?

Comment: Is it possible to match `VAR-A` in `{{a.b.VAR-A}}` ?

Comment: This fails when we have boolean values like VAR-F: True