# Extract Key Value pairs which matches the regex in YAML with boolean values

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

I have this below `YAML` input and I am trying to extract shown output using `yq`. I want to remove pairs where key name `(VAR-A)` in value `{{a.b.VAR-A}}` (after `a.b.`) matches and If I have more than one `{{a.b.VAR-A}}` in values separated by `-` , I want to keep them.

```
VAR-A: '{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-B: '{{a.b.VAR-B}}'
VAR-C: v0.0
VAR-D: '{{a.b.VAR-D}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-E: '{{a.b.VAR-C}}-{{a.b.VAR-B}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-F: True
```

**Expected Output:**

```
VAR-C: v0.0
VAR-D: '{{a.b.VAR-D}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-E: '{{a.b.VAR-C}}-{{a.b.VAR-B}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-F: True
```

This question works if I have all strings, but it fails when I have `boolean` value in `yaml`. [Extract Key Value pairs which matches the regex in YAML using yq/sed/grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422329/extract-key-value-pairs-which-matches-the-regex-in-yaml-using-yq-sed-grep/67424160#67424160)

I get below error:

> Error: cannot substitute with !!bool, can only substitute strings. Hint: Most often you'll want to use '|=' over '=' for this operation.

Comment: Where is your code?  And yq command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two very different extant "yq" projects: a Python-based one, which is the focus of Part 1 below, and a Go-based one, which is the focus of Part 2.

#### Part 1

```
python-yq 'del(.[] | select( ( type == "string" and test("^{{a[.]b[.][^}]*}}$" ))))' so-vars.yaml
```

or

```
python-yq  'map_values( select( ( type == "string" and test("^{{a[.]b[.][^}]*}}$" )) | not))' so-vars.yaml
```

##### Output:

```
{
  "VAR-C": "v0.0",
  "VAR-D": "{{a.b.VAR-D}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}",
  "VAR-E": "{{a.b.VAR-C}}-{{a.b.VAR-B}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}",
  "VAR-F": true
}
```

#### Part 2

The Go-based version of yq that I have (4.6.3) might not be able to handle your requirements directly, but here's a solution that uses this yq to translate to and from JSON, and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to do the rest:

```
yq -j eval . input.yaml |
  jq  'del(.[] | select(( type == "string" and test("^{{a[.]b[.][^}]*}}$" ))))' > tmp.json
yq -P eval . tmp.json
```

The `del`-free version of the jq program:

```
map_values( select( type == "string" and test("^{{a[.]b[.][^}]*}}$" | not)
```

##### Output:

```
VAR-C: v0.0
VAR-D: '{{a.b.VAR-D}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-E: '{{a.b.VAR-C}}-{{a.b.VAR-B}}-{{a.b.VAR-A}}'
VAR-F: true
```